Как пишутся образные названия военных ситуаций?
Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как пишутся названия, описывающие те или иные военные ситуации на конкретной местности? Нужны ли кавычки и/или прописные буквы? Например: Дебальцевский котёл, Авдеевский цветок, Очерётинский выступ, Северский балкон...

• Я думаю, что вот в этих сочетаниях первое слово пишется с прописной буквы, второе — со строчной, а кавычки не нужны:
Дебальцевский котёл, Очеретинский выступ, Северский балкон.
И действует здесь такое правило Розенталя:

1. В названиях исторических эпох и событий первое слово (и все имена собственные) пишется с прописной буквы; родовые наименования (эпоха, век и т. п.) пишутся со строчной буквы: ...Куликовская битва, Бородинский бой...

Да, предполагаю, что это названия ситуаций, связанных с военным делом и названных так по месту действия:
Дебальцево — Дебальцевский котёл;
Очеретино — Очеретинский выступ;
Северск — Северский балкон.

Предпосылкой «попадания в котёл» является наличие выступа на линии фронта. Крупнейшие выступы в военной истории имеют название дуга, например, Курская дуга.

• А вот "Авдеевский цветок", возможно, стоит взять в кавычки — если это название схемы, плана или выбора действий (например, план "Барбаросса", операция "Цитадель").
Названия исторических эпох, событий, съездов, геологических периодов
Котёл (военное дело)
"Авдеевский цветок" начинает распускаться
